# Apply an operation to some elements of a vector by using indices

Tags: r, vector

I've got a fairly basic question concerning vector operations in R. I want to apply a certain operation (i.e. increment) to specific elements of a vector by using a vector containing the indices of the elements.

For example:

```
ind <- c(2,5,8)
vec <- seq(1,10)
```

I want to add 1 to the 2nd, 5th and 8th element of vec. In the end I'd like to have:

```
vec <- c(1,3,3,4,6,6,7,9,8,10)
```

I tried

```
vec[ind] + 1
```

but that returns only the three elements. I could use a for-loop, of course, but knowing R, I'm sure there's a more elegant way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to assign it

```
 vec[ind] <- vec[ind] + 1
 vec
 #[1]  1  3  3  4  6  6  7  9  9 10
```